# numpy#genfromtxt raise an IOError while the txt file is empty

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

Then [genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) method of numpy load an ndarray from a text file.
However, if the text file is empty, the method would raised an `IOError` while I expected an empty `ndarray`:

> IOError: End-of-file reached before encountering data.

Is there any solution to get an empty ndarray if the text file is emtpy?

Comment: Update your NumPy. The error has been changed into a warning: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/72ab385d17d9067f97652aeae87a820f7de41298

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `try` block to return an empty array on error:

```
try:
    a = np.genfromtext("filename.txt")
except IOError:
    a = np.array([]) # Or np.empty or np.zeros...
```

Comment: Yes, that's works. But is there exists some parameter of `genfromtxt` to make this behave?

Comment: I disagree that it is misbehaving.  The function is supposed to return data, and if it cannot there must have been an error so it raises one.  It is the functionality I would expect.  But as you can see from it's [documentation page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) there is no such option.  (I admit they don't specify what happens when the file is empty).